# Oracle and Postgres client code in the same task?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I ran into an unexpected problem: I need a task that talks to Postgres (over libpq) and Oracle through Oracle's shared library libclnt. However, a task which links both libs in cores. That is, a C/C++ program which connects to oracle, and connects to PG --- and nothing else --- will core while connecting to Oracle in the OCIServerAttach method. The problem appears that there's significant overlap in ssh/ldap/crypto libs that are inside libclnt loaded at runtime, and those ssh/ldap/crypto libraries linked in which libpq depends. Has anybody made this work?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do that is to load the shared library at run time using `dlopen(3)` while using the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag. This is specific to the GNU C library, so it will only work on systems using that library.

According to [the documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> `RTLD_DEEPBIND` (since glibc 2.3.4)
>
> Place  the lookup scope of the symbols in this shared object ahead of the global scope.  This means that a self-contained object
> will use its own symbols in preference to global symbols with the same name contained in objects that have already been loaded.

Then each library will use symbols from the libraries it is linked with.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The fixes we're:

- link only .a files for ora and pg (no shared ora lib) plus a few ora .o files
- sequence libs correctly; ora then pg then other libs
- prefer `-l<lib> over ..../lib<lib>.a` to avoid dup'd symbols

This I believe avoids runtime symbol resolution issues which mixes pg and oracle code.